# Webdriver not working in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to deploy my scraper on Google Cloudrun, however I'm getting below error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to 

start: exited abnormally.
at check_response (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242)
at execute (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321)
at start_session (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:252)
at __init__ (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:157)
at __init__ (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:76)
at scrape_refresher (/app/refresher_news_crawler.py:32)
at run_crawlers (/app/main.py:30)
at dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1936)
at full_dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1950)
at reraise (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:39)
at handle_user_exception (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1821)
at wrapped_function (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py:165)
at full_dispatch_request (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:1952)
at wsgi_app (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py:2447)
```

I've assumed this will be mismatch of version, but since my docker file is downloading latest stable version `85.0.4183.83`, even after matching this to `chromedriver-binary==85.0.4183.83.0`
the error keeps occurring, I've also tried the latest version of chromdriver-binary which is `85.0.4183.87.0` but the result is the same.

Docker file:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Install manually all the missing libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service wget libasound2 libgbm1 libappindicator3-1 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils

# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install
# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip install firebase_admin
RUN pip install flask_cors
RUN pip install selenium
RUN pip install firebase_admin
RUN pip install chromedriver-binary==85.0.4183.83.0
# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

There are no issues during installation, only during run. Any help is much appreciated.

Chrome init:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1024,768")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Are you running the driver as root? If so try using the --no-sandbox option as the first argument. Although I would recommend not running it as root because of vulnerabilities.

Comment: @FelipeEmerim using `--no-sandbox` has solved it, please post the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running the driver as root? If so try using the `--no-sandbox` option as the first argument to your driver. Although I would recommend not running it as root because of vulnerabilities.

I have seen from your comment that this solved the issue, but I recommend you create a non root user to run your services if security is really important in your case.